# Navbar buttons in <head> moves (expands downward) with grid padding in <body>

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to develop a Jquery mobile app but run into a problem which I could not find an answer in the web. The app has a navbar with 4 buttons and a 2-column grid to hold image links. The problem is when I add top padding to the block elements the left 2 buttons in navbar moves down. Can somebody please help! Thanks.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
<title>Citrus IPM Test_1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../download18Dec13/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="../download18Dec13/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../download18Dec13/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/my_style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                            <li><a href=# class="ui-btn-active ui-state-  persist">Insects</a></li>
                    <li><a href=# > Diseases</a></li>
                <li><a href=# >Inspection</a></li>
                <li><a href=# >Biosecurity</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    </div>



    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a href="frw.html"> <img href="#" src="./img/frw_main.png" alt="FRW"> <br>Fuller's rose weevil</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <a href="lbam.html"> <img href="#" src="./img/frw_main.png" alt="LBAM"><br>Light brown apple moth</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a href="crs.html"> <img href="#" src="./img/frw_main.png" alt="CRS"><br>California red scale</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <a href="cgw.html"> <img href="#" src="./img/frw_main.png" alt="CGW"><br>Citrus gall wasp</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="footer" data-id="footer.home" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
         <div data-role=navbar>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href=# data-icon=arrow-l></a></li>
                    <li><a href=# data-icon=refresh></a></li>
                    <li><a href=# data-icon=arrow-r></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

CSS file:

.ui-navbar .ui-btn-text {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
           font-size:10px;
    padding:0px; important!
 }


.ui-block-a{
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:9px;
//height:70px;
//width:50px;
display:block;
padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.ui-block-b{
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:9px;
//height:70px;
//width:50px;
display:block;
padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

header{height:50px;width:auto;}
img{
width:auto;
//height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you said. Its because your adding a padding-top to the first two `<li>`.. so the elements with class `.ui-block-b` and `.ui-block-b` gets bigger in height.. padding are added inside the border of the elements thus making the `<a>` elements contained inside it go down.

[UPDATED]
I noticed in your css that your defining a

```
 .ui-block-b{
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:9px;
  //height:70px;
  //width:50px;
  display:block;
  padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
```

and i think that this class is already being used by jquery. so the fact that your adding this `padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;` will reflect the ones that jquery labels with `class = ui-block-b`.

To see my point try inspecting the DOM with firebug or pressing F12 if your using google chrome. you will see that all `<li>` under the `<div data-role="navbar">` now has the `class = ui-block-<*>`. so they get affected. My suggestion is try adding another classname if you want to override the look of your page with an existing classes from a library.

Like this `class = "ui-block-b my_class_name"`

and alter the look of ui-block-b by defining styles for my_class_name class. SO that other elements using class ui-block-b will not be affected.